# Returning JSON in an axios response causing backslashes to be added

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to get some json from a URL via axios

Here's my code, the json is returned in the "response"

```
axios.post("URL_TO_GET", {
            id: id
        })
        .then(function (response) {

               newObj = response.data;
                vm.sections.splice(index+1, 0, newObj);
          }
```

Here's a sample response

```
{ "id":1,"fixed": false }
```

However, when I try to splice, backslashes are getting added to the data like so

```
{ \"id\":1,\"fixed\":false }
```

Is there anyway to prevent the backslashes to be added?

Comment: It is not actually a backslash, it is an escape for the double code. Modify your newObj before adding to the sections.

Comment: @ChitKhine can you explain how to do this?